# PowerTools items are displaying in disabled mode

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have installed the PowerTools successfully in SDL Tridion 2011. But all PowerTools menu items are disabled. I want to use Image Uploader tool.

Can any one please help me? Am I missing any setting for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flush your browser cache.  Also, give permissions to network service on the powertools folder.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The power tools are contextual based on the type of 'area' you are working.  For example the **Image Upload** is only available in **Folder** areas.   Can you confirm you are attempting to use the power tools as intended as I've never seen this before in anyone's environment.

Comment: Yes, i am trying like this way for Image uploader, even i have also tried, with Page Publisher with the structure group, But still its in disable mode.